# Change dispute message on per-site Meta

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, locked-questions

Currently, if content is disputed on a per-site Meta, the message is.

> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info visit meta.

...with a link to that site's Meta.

Well, I'm already on Meta. Can this be changed? Or is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

Comment: That's [status-bydesign], its purpose being to trap you in an infinite loop.

Comment: Does this mean we now need a meta for every meta for every site? Meta-ception! Also, no freehand circles in your post, -1

Comment: Do you want it to point to chat? Maybe ask "do you want to play a game"?

Comment: @jcolebrand That'd be better than being in an infinite loop...

Comment: @jcolebrand Chat would be good, but it wouldn't work for users with less than 20 rep.

Answer (score 6):

Why do we say "For more info visit meta" anyway?  That would imply that there's a post there, somewhere on the first page, where we address specifically the locking of the post in question.  Or, maybe we're supposed to search for some FAQ entry that explains what's happening?

Bah.  I say we get rid of the phrase entirely.  We can always post a comment on the locked post that points *specifically* to a  <s>cage fight</s> Meta entry, if there is one.

Comment: That's true....

Comment: I feel like in order to lock it with that message, we should have to provide a meta Q ID in the first place. Meaning: "go make a brief meta Q, bring that link back to the P, lock it, go back to meta, fill in any more details". Just like VtC: Dupe works, gotta provide a post ID.

Comment: @jcolebrand: That seems like a lot of work, if all I really want to do is freeze a question for an hour to let everyone calm down.

Comment: But the message says "see meta", I thought we had one that _didn't_ require "see meta". I'm saying if there's a message to see meta, it should ask for a link. http://i.imgur.com/RCKz1.png

Comment: The "Content Dispute" one is the only one that says "See meta."  But the other ones like "Historical significance" don't really fit, if what you're after is a cooling off period.